# Don't proximity alerts get fired by a test provider?

Tags: android, location

I have an app in which I use a testprovider to generate gps fixes for testing. It generates onlocationchanged events, as expected. However, I have proximity alerts, and these do not get fired by the testprovider. They do fire when I run the app in the emulator and I send gps fixes via ddms. The api docs say "Internally, this method uses both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER", from which you might conclude that proximity alerts aren't fired when you use a test provider. Can someone confirm this? Or am I mistaken, and my code is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried anything? plz post your code here so that people may help you:)

Comment: My code works when I inject a geo fix in the emulator. Same code doesn't work when I inject the same geo fix through a test provider, whether I name that test provider "gps" or otherwise. I created a workaround, I'm just curious if anyone else ever tried to use a test provide with proximity alerts.